# Maven build working with java8 but not working with more than java11

Tags: maven, java-8, java-14

I had  a Maven project which is running on java 8 without any errors .. but the same running on java 11 or more is giving compile time errors

1)Failed to execute goal com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2:maven-jaxb-plugin:1.1.1:generate (generate-request-schema) on project maven-project: Execution generate-request-schema of goal com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2:maven-jaxb-plugin:1.1.1:generate failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2:maven-jaxb-plugin:1.1.1:generate: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null

2)Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project

3. Incompatible version for few claases which does not give this error on java8

Comment: The jaxb plugin version is ancient old also the maven-compiler-plugin is also ancient old... You have to upgrade the plugins and also the deps etc.